# Trouble using Liquibase Docker image with Azure Sql AAD Auth

Tags: azure-sql-database, liquibase, azure-ad-msal

I'm having some trouble getting the base liquibase docker image to perform an update against an azure sql database using Active Directory authentication.

The specific error I am getting is

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Connection could not be created to jdbc:sqlserver://REDACTED.database.windows.net:1433;database=REDACTED;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.  Failed to load MSAL4J Java library for performing ActiveDirectoryPassword authentication.
```

Following the documentation from Liquibase I attempted to load the MSAL4J jar along with its dependencies into the class path to no avail.
Here is my script:

```
$path = $repositoryPath -replace '\\','/'

$internalVolumeMap = "$path/db:/liquibase/changelog" -replace '\\','/'

$internalResourceMap = "$path/db/resources:/liquibase/classpath" -replace '\\','/'

$connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://REDACTED.windows.net:1433;database=REDACTED;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword"

docker run --rm `
           -v $internalResourceMap `
           -v $internalVolumeMap `
           liquibase/liquibase:4.5.0 `
           --url=$connectionString `
           --changeLogFile=/liquibase/changelog/liquibaseChangeLog.json `
           --username=REDACTED `
           --password="REDACTED" `
           --classpath="/liquibase/changelog:/liquibase/classpath/msal4j-1.11.0.jar" `
            update
```

There is a bunch of information about how to get this working without using docker - but I have not come across much in the way of examples leveraging the liquibase docker image. So this is a shot in the dark that maybe someone has run into this before or has done this before and could point me in the right direction.

Comment: The work around here is remove the double quote ("") from the connectionStrings. Take a look at this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/tds/clients

Comment: I am not following this comment - Powershell requires the quotes around the string value in this case. I think the connection string is valid else it wouldn't have got to the point of trying to load MSAL to perform the authentication to the server.

Comment: Try adding msal4j-1.11.0.jar file in the liquibase/lib directory inside the docker container instead of liquibase/classpath.

Comment: @Aditi - Is that possible without building a custom docker image? Looking at the liquibase base image it seems like liquibase/classpath is intended for what you'd normally place in lib for a local installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are probably not requiring this anymore, wanted to post a solution that worked for our build process.

We ran into a similar issue with `ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal` authentication but the same should apply for the other forms of AAD auths.

Liquibase does not include the `Msal4j.jar` or the dependencies required. You need to obtain these from an outside source ex: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/msal4j.

Easiest way is to have maven copy the dependencies locally in the build - `dependency:copy-dependencies` targeting a `pom.xml` file like so.

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>company-artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

We are using the latest docker image at this time (4.20).

```
docker run 
  liquibase/liquibase:4.20 
  --rm 
  -v "build_artifact:/liquibase/changelog" 
  -v "build_artifact/target/dependency:/liquibase/lib" 
  --url="url" 
  --changeLogFile="changeLogFile.xml"
  --username="username"
  --password="password"
  update
```

This line is what places the dependencies into the `liquibase/lib` that maven downloaded:

`-v "build_artifact/target/dependency:/liquibase/lib"`